# Select from 2 tables only the new entries in table 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I got 2 tables, Customers and Payment. I'm trying to select only the new customers that have payments in the specified month and year, and no previous payments in another month.

**table Customer**

id - name

**table Payment**

id  -  id_customer  -  month  -  year  -  amount

```
SELECT * FROM customer, payment
WHERE Customer.id = Payment.id_customer
AND month = '$month'
AND year = '$year'
```

That gets me all the payments in a specific month and year, but I don't know how to exclude all the customers that had other previous payments.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe `select name, id from customer where id not in (select id_customer from payment) AND month = '$month' AND year = '$year'`? ... or maybe an outer join..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you could achieve this without a third table. What you can do is create a third table with all the ids that you have selected in query and update it every time you run a select query.
Then the below query might work:

```
SELECT * FROM customer c, payment p WHERE c.id = p.id_customer 
AND month =  '$month'AND year = '$year'AND p.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM 
third_table)
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: This is such a bad approach, using a third table when that isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first date of payment, use `GROUP BY`.  But, you will have to convert the value to something like a date first:

```
SELECT p.id_customer, MIN(CONCAT_WS, '-', p.year, p.month)) as first_yyyymm
FROM payment p
GROUP BY p.id_customer;
```

You should store the payment date as a date.

Comment: I know is not the correct way to store a date, "month" is only a number from 1- 12, same as the "year" (2015 - 2017), but is the way the DB was created, I can´t change it now.

Comment: @Raychu150 You can use the date functions to easily compare your month index.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract

Comment: Thanks for the info, that´s helpful, but I double check and is even worse, the month is a string with the name of the month, not even a number.